# How to space out these 3 button

Tags: html, css, html-email

Used an email signature generator to do this and it included 1 button but I need to add 2 more.  But I want the buttons to be the same width and then evenly spaced under the width of the entire signature.

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="150" style="vertical-align: middle;"><span class="template3__ImageContainer-sc-vj949k-0 jeScQV" style="margin-right: 20px; display: block;"><img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/msgsndr/4v9YnFV91CVUbuwS6IF5/media/64f8b3af63e5711da26d77bf.png" role="presentation" width="130" class="image__StyledImage-sc-hupvqm-0 gYgOut" style="max-width: 130px;"></span></td>
              <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                <h2 color="#000" class="name__NameContainer-sc-1m457h3-0 jxbGUj" style="margin: 0px; font-size: 18px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-weight: 600;"><span>Aaron</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>Rajchel</span></h2>
                <p color="#000" font-size="medium" class="job-title__Container-sc-1hmtp73-0 ifJNJc" style="margin: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px;"><span>Owner</span></p>
                <p color="#000" font-size="medium" class="company-details__CompanyContainer-sc-j5pyy8-0 VnOLK" style="margin: 0px; font-weight: 500; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px;"><span>LandscapAI</span></p>
                <p color="#000" font-size="medium" class="custom-field__CustomFieldContainer-sc-190n2f-0 dKSugh" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); margin: 0px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px;"><span>Automation + AI = Grow</span></p>
              </td>
              <td width="30">
                <div style="width: 30px;"></div>
              </td>
              <td color="#4358a7" direction="vertical" width="1" height="auto" class="color-divider__Divider-sc-1h38qjv-0 llIisW" style="width: 1px; border-bottom: none; border-left: 1px solid rgb(67, 88, 167);"></td>
              <td width="30">
                <div style="width: 30px;"></div>
              </td>
              <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr height="25" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                      <td width="30" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="vertical-align: bottom;"><span color="#4358a7" width="11" class="contact-info__IconWrapper-sc-mmkjr6-1 bglVXe" style="display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167);"><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/53/tools/email-signature-generator/icons/phone-icon-2x.png" color="#4358a7" alt="mobilePhone" width="13" class="contact-info__ContactLabelIcon-sc-mmkjr6-0 cnkwri" style="display: block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167);"></span></td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                      <td style="padding: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><a href="tel:855-242-4769" color="#000" class="contact-info__ExternalLink-sc-mmkjr6-2 ibLXSU" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 12px;"><span>855-242-4769</span></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr height="25" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                      <td width="30" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="vertical-align: bottom;"><span color="#4358a7" width="11" class="contact-info__IconWrapper-sc-mmkjr6-1 bglVXe" style="display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167);"><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/53/tools/email-signature-generator/icons/email-icon-2x.png" color="#4358a7" alt="emailAddress" width="13" class="contact-info__ContactLabelIcon-sc-mmkjr6-0 cnkwri" style="display: block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167);"></span></td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                      <td style="padding: 0px;"><a href="mailto:aaron@landscap.ai" color="#000" class="contact-info__ExternalLink-sc-mmkjr6-2 ibLXSU" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 12px;"><span>aaron@landscap.ai</span></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr height="25" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                      <td width="30" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="vertical-align: bottom;"><span color="#4358a7" width="11" class="contact-info__IconWrapper-sc-mmkjr6-1 bglVXe" style="display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167);"><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/53/tools/email-signature-generator/icons/link-icon-2x.png" color="#4358a7" alt="website" width="13" class="contact-info__ContactLabelIcon-sc-mmkjr6-0 cnkwri" style="display: block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167);"></span></td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                      <td style="padding: 0px;"><a href="//www.landscap.ai" color="#000" class="contact-info__ExternalLink-sc-mmkjr6-2 ibLXSU" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 12px;"><span>www.landscap.ai</span></a></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="width: 100%; vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td height="30"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td color="#4358a7" direction="horizontal" width="auto" height="1" class="color-divider__Divider-sc-1h38qjv-0 llIisW" style="width: 100%; border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(67, 88, 167); border-left: none; display: block;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="30"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="width: 100%; vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align: right; vertical-align: top;"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="width: 100%; vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td>
                <tr><span style="display: block;">
    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://updates.landscap.ai/widget/bookings/demolandscapai" color="#4358a7" class="cta__CtaButton-sc-sq0d6i-0 kGNEzu" style="border-width: 6px 12px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: 700; text-decoration: none; text-align: center; line-height: 40px; font-size: 12px; border-radius: 3px;">Customer Demo</a>
    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://updates.landscap.ai/widget/bookings/customersupportmeet" color="#4358a7" class="cta__CtaButton-sc-sq0d6i-0 kGNEzu" style="border-width: 6px 12px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: 700; text-decoration: none; text-align: center; line-height: 40px; font-size: 12px; border-radius: 3px;">Customer Support</a>
    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://updates.landscap.ai/widget/bookings/affiliatedemo" color="#4358a7" class="cta__CtaButton-sc-sq0d6i-0 kGNEzu" style="border-width: 6px 12px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: 700; text-decoration: none; text-align: center; line-height: 40px; font-size: 12px; border-radius: 3px;">Affiliate Demo</a>
</span></tr>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It's been 20 years since I coded in HTML but I messed around and couldn't get it to work.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Just to re-iterate what others have said below: that whole rendering should be done without tables these days..... and the likes of "flex" or "grid" will cut down the quantity of html you need quite dramatically.... though you will have to spend time learning more about CSS

Comment: But the context is email https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=flex and https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-display-grid/

Comment: @CodeGorilla as Nathan already correctly said and linked the question was specifically labeled and mentioned as an HTML-Email question. Email providers still support mainly HTML4 and inline-style (has historic reasons because HTML5 is not specified by W3C but recommended by WHATWG). SO you have only an insufficient support for Flexbox, Grid or CSS at all. The email generator correctly styled the email with tabels and inline-style. This is the only correct and fully supported way of styling here.

Answer (score 1):

The buttons are centered using style="text-align: center;", and they are evenly spaced within the width of the entire signature. This should give you three evenly spaced buttons with the same width under the signature. You can adjust the button text and links as needed.

Full refactored code:

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI"
    style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI"
                    style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="150" style="vertical-align: middle;"><span
                                    class="template3__ImageContainer-sc-vj949k-0 jeScQV"
                                    style="margin-right: 20px; display: block;"><img
                                        src="https://storage.googleapis.com/msgsndr/4v9YnFV91CVUbuwS6IF5/media/64f8b3af63e5711da26d77bf.png"
                                        role="presentation" width="130" class="image__StyledImage-sc-hupvqm-0 gYgOut"
                                        style="max-width: 130px;"></span></td>
                            <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                <h2 color="#000" class="name__NameContainer-sc-1m457h3-0 jxbGUj"
                                    style="margin: 0px; font-size: 18px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-weight: 600;">
                                    <span>Aaron</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>Rajchel</span>
                                </h2>
                                <p color="#000" font-size="medium" class="job-title__Container-sc-1hmtp73-0 ifJNJc"
                                    style="margin: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px;">
                                    <span>Owner</span>
                                </p>
                                <p color="#000" font-size="medium"
                                    class="company-details__CompanyContainer-sc-j5pyy8-0 VnOLK"
                                    style="margin: 0px; font-weight: 500; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px;">
                                    <span>LandscapAI</span>
                                </p>
                                <p color="#000" font-size="medium"
                                    class="custom-field__CustomFieldContainer-sc-190n2f-0 dKSugh"
                                    style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); margin: 0px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px;">
                                    <span>Automation + AI = Grow</span>
                                </p>
                            </td>
                            <td width="30">
                                <div style="width: 30px;"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td color="#4358a7" direction="vertical" width="1" height="auto"
                                class="color-divider__Divider-sc-1h38qjv-0 llIisW"
                                style="width: 1px; border-bottom: none; border-left: 1px solid rgb(67, 88, 167);"></td>
                            <td width="30">
                                <div style="width: 30px;"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI"
                                    style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr height="25" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                            <td width="30" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
                                                    class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI"
                                                    style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td style="vertical-align: bottom;"><span color="#4358a7"
                                                                    width="11"
                                                                    class="contact-info__IconWrapper-sc-mmkjr6-1 bglVXe"
                                                                    style="display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167);"><img
                                                                        src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/53/tools/email-signature-generator/icons/phone-icon-2x.png"
                                                                        color="#4358a7" alt="mobilePhone" width="13"
                                                                        class="contact-info__ContactLabelIcon-sc-mmkjr6-0 cnkwri"
                                                                        style="display: block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167);"></span>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="padding: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><a href="tel:855-242-4769"
                                                    color="#000" class="contact-info__ExternalLink-sc-mmkjr6-2 ibLXSU"
                                                    style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 12px;"><span>855-242-4769</span></a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr height="25" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                            <td width="30" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
                                                    class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI"
                                                    style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td style="vertical-align: bottom;"><span color="#4358a7"
                                                                    width="11"
                                                                    class="contact-info__IconWrapper-sc-mmkjr6-1 bglVXe"
                                                                    style="display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167);"><img
                                                                        src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/53/tools/email-signature-generator/icons/email-icon-2x.png"
                                                                        color="#4358a7" alt="emailAddress" width="13"
                                                                        class="contact-info__ContactLabelIcon-sc-mmkjr6-0 cnkwri"
                                                                        style="display: block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167);"></span>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="padding: 0px;"><a href="mailto:aaron@landscap.ai" color="#000"
                                                    class="contact-info__ExternalLink-sc-mmkjr6-2 ibLXSU"
                                                    style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 12px;"><span>aaron@landscap.ai</span></a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr height="25" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                            <td width="30" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
                                                    class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI"
                                                    style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td style="vertical-align: bottom;"><span color="#4358a7"
                                                                    width="11"
                                                                    class="contact-info__IconWrapper-sc-mmkjr6-1 bglVXe"
                                                                    style="display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167);"><img
                                                                        src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/53/tools/email-signature-generator/icons/link-icon-2x.png"
                                                                        color="#4358a7" alt="website" width="13"
                                                                        class="contact-info__ContactLabelIcon-sc-mmkjr6-0 cnkwri"
                                                                        style="display: block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167);"></span>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="padding: 0px;"><a href="//www.landscap.ai" color="#000"
                                                    class="contact-info__ExternalLink-sc-mmkjr6-2 ibLXSU"
                                                    style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 12px;"><span>www.landscap.ai</span></a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI"
                    style="width: 100%; vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="30"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td color="#4358a7" direction="horizontal" width="auto" height="1"
                                class="color-divider__Divider-sc-1h38qjv-0 llIisW"
                                style="width: 100%; border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(67, 88, 167); border-left: none; display: block;">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="30"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- Add a row for the buttons here -->
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top;">
                                <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"
                                    href="https://updates.landscap.ai/widget/bookings/demolandscapai" color="#4358a7"
                                    class="cta__CtaButton-sc-sq0d6i-0 kGNEzu"
                                    style="border-width: 6px 12px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: 700; text-decoration: none; text-align: center; line-height: 40px; font-size: 12px; border-radius: 3px; width: 120px;">Customer
                                    Demo</a>
                                <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"
                                    href="https://updates.landscap.ai/widget/bookings/customersupportmeet"
                                    color="#4358a7" class="cta__CtaButton-sc-sq0d6i-0 kGNEzu"
                                    style="border-width: 6px 12px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: 700; text-decoration: none; text-align: center; line-height: 40px; font-size: 12px; border-radius: 3px; width: 120px;">Customer
                                    Support</a>
                                <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"
                                    href="https://updates.landscap.ai/widget/bookings/affiliatedemo" color="#4358a7"
                                    class="cta__CtaButton-sc-sq0d6i-0 kGNEzu"
                                    style="border-width: 6px 12px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: 700; text-decoration: none; text-align: center; line-height: 40px; font-size: 12px; border-radius: 3px; width: 120px;">Affiliate
                                    Demo</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- End of buttons row -->
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is corrected part of your code :

```html
<!-- Add a row for the buttons here -->
                  <tr>
                     <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top;">
                        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://updates.landscap.ai/widget/bookings/demolandscapai" color="#4358a7" class="cta__CtaButton-sc-sq0d6i-0 kGNEzu" style="border-width: 6px 12px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: 700; text-decoration: none; text-align: center; line-height: 40px; font-size: 12px; border-radius: 3px; width: 100px;">Customer Demo</a>
                        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://updates.landscap.ai/widget/bookings/customersupportmeet" color="#4358a7" class="cta__CtaButton-sc-sq0d6i-0 kGNEzu" style="border-width: 6px 12px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: 700; text-decoration: none; text-align: center; line-height: 40px; font-size: 12px; border-radius: 3px; width: 100px;">Support</a>
                        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://updates.landscap.ai/widget/bookings/affiliatedemo" color="#4358a7" class="cta__CtaButton-sc-sq0d6i-0 kGNEzu" style="border-width: 6px 12px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: 700; text-decoration: none; text-align: center; line-height: 40px; font-size: 12px; border-radius: 3px; width: 100px;">Affiliate Demo</a>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <!-- End of buttons row -->
```

Comment: You can remove your `Note` as this is specifically a HTML-Email question where you can neither use external CSS nor classes. HTML-Emails are correctly styled with inline style to provide the best support with all email clients as HTML-Emails are also mainly HTML4 based.

Comment: Thanks for the info, will do the same!

Comment: @tacoshy -  thanks for the information, but at the beginning some have a FAQ that what to do next. Considering your suggestion will update this changes in future .

Comment: Keeping all side by side doesn't give any space around the buttons and does not stretch across fully. Not sure if this is a valid answer (yet)?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, that the anchors are all in a single cell (`td`).
To solve it you have to put them into different cells in the same table row (`tr`).

Then you can use the `align` attribute to align the anchors at the left, center and right side of the cell:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="left"><a href="#">Button 1</a></td>
    <td align="center"><a href="#">Button 1</a></td>
    <td align="right"><a href="#">Button 1</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="150" style="vertical-align: middle;"><span class="template3__ImageContainer-sc-vj949k-0 jeScQV" style="margin-right: 20px; display: block;"><img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/msgsndr/4v9YnFV91CVUbuwS6IF5/media/64f8b3af63e5711da26d77bf.png" role="presentation" width="130" class="image__StyledImage-sc-hupvqm-0 gYgOut" style="max-width: 130px;"></span></td>
              <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                <h2 color="#000" class="name__NameContainer-sc-1m457h3-0 jxbGUj" style="margin: 0px; font-size: 18px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-weight: 600;"><span>Aaron</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>Rajchel</span></h2>
                <p color="#000" font-size="medium" class="job-title__Container-sc-1hmtp73-0 ifJNJc" style="margin: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px;"><span>Owner</span></p>
                <p color="#000" font-size="medium" class="company-details__CompanyContainer-sc-j5pyy8-0 VnOLK" style="margin: 0px; font-weight: 500; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px;"><span>LandscapAI</span></p>
                <p color="#000" font-size="medium" class="custom-field__CustomFieldContainer-sc-190n2f-0 dKSugh" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); margin: 0px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px;"><span>Automation + AI = Grow</span></p>
              </td>
              <td width="30">
                <div style="width: 30px;"></div>
              </td>
              <td color="#4358a7" direction="vertical" width="1" height="auto" class="color-divider__Divider-sc-1h38qjv-0 llIisW" style="width: 1px; border-bottom: none; border-left: 1px solid rgb(67, 88, 167);"></td>
              <td width="30">
                <div style="width: 30px;"></div>
              </td>
              <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr height="25" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                      <td width="30" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="vertical-align: bottom;"><span color="#4358a7" width="11" class="contact-info__IconWrapper-sc-mmkjr6-1 bglVXe" style="display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167);"><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/53/tools/email-signature-generator/icons/phone-icon-2x.png" color="#4358a7" alt="mobilePhone" width="13" class="contact-info__ContactLabelIcon-sc-mmkjr6-0 cnkwri" style="display: block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167);"></span></td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                      <td style="padding: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><a href="tel:855-242-4769" color="#000" class="contact-info__ExternalLink-sc-mmkjr6-2 ibLXSU" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 12px;"><span>855-242-4769</span></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr height="25" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                      <td width="30" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="vertical-align: bottom;"><span color="#4358a7" width="11" class="contact-info__IconWrapper-sc-mmkjr6-1 bglVXe" style="display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167);"><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/53/tools/email-signature-generator/icons/email-icon-2x.png" color="#4358a7" alt="emailAddress" width="13" class="contact-info__ContactLabelIcon-sc-mmkjr6-0 cnkwri" style="display: block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167);"></span></td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                      <td style="padding: 0px;"><a href="mailto:aaron@landscap.ai" color="#000" class="contact-info__ExternalLink-sc-mmkjr6-2 ibLXSU" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 12px;"><span>aaron@landscap.ai</span></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr height="25" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                      <td width="30" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="vertical-align: bottom;"><span color="#4358a7" width="11" class="contact-info__IconWrapper-sc-mmkjr6-1 bglVXe" style="display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167);"><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/53/tools/email-signature-generator/icons/link-icon-2x.png" color="#4358a7" alt="website" width="13" class="contact-info__ContactLabelIcon-sc-mmkjr6-0 cnkwri" style="display: block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167);"></span></td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                      <td style="padding: 0px;"><a href="//www.landscap.ai" color="#000" class="contact-info__ExternalLink-sc-mmkjr6-2 ibLXSU" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 12px;"><span>www.landscap.ai</span></a></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="width: 100%; vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td height="30"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td color="#4358a7" direction="horizontal" width="auto" height="1" class="color-divider__Divider-sc-1h38qjv-0 llIisW" style="width: 100%; border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(67, 88, 167); border-left: none; display: block;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="30"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="width: 100%; vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align: right; vertical-align: top;"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="width: 100%; vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="left">
    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://updates.landscap.ai/widget/bookings/demolandscapai" color="#4358a7" class="cta__CtaButton-sc-sq0d6i-0 kGNEzu" style="border-width: 6px 12px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: 700; text-decoration: none; text-align: center; line-height: 40px; font-size: 12px; border-radius: 3px;">Customer Demo</a>
              </td>
              <td align="center">
    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://updates.landscap.ai/widget/bookings/customersupportmeet" color="#4358a7" class="cta__CtaButton-sc-sq0d6i-0 kGNEzu" style="border-width: 6px 12px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: 700; text-decoration: none; text-align: center; line-height: 40px; font-size: 12px; border-radius: 3px;">Customer Support</a>
              </td>
              <td align="right">
    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://updates.landscap.ai/widget/bookings/affiliatedemo" color="#4358a7" class="cta__CtaButton-sc-sq0d6i-0 kGNEzu" style="border-width: 6px 12px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: 700; text-decoration: none; text-align: center; line-height: 40px; font-size: 12px; border-radius: 3px;">Affiliate Demo</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Table layouts are not popular anymore like they were 20 years ago. You can do this with flexbox:

```css
div.flex-container > a {
  flex-basis: 120px
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="150" style="vertical-align: middle;"><span class="template3__ImageContainer-sc-vj949k-0 jeScQV" style="margin-right: 20px; display: block;"><img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/msgsndr/4v9YnFV91CVUbuwS6IF5/media/64f8b3af63e5711da26d77bf.png" role="presentation" width="130" class="image__StyledImage-sc-hupvqm-0 gYgOut" style="max-width: 130px;"></span></td>
              <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                <h2 color="#000" class="name__NameContainer-sc-1m457h3-0 jxbGUj" style="margin: 0px; font-size: 18px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-weight: 600;"><span>Aaron</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>Rajchel</span></h2>
                <p color="#000" font-size="medium" class="job-title__Container-sc-1hmtp73-0 ifJNJc" style="margin: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px;"><span>Owner</span></p>
                <p color="#000" font-size="medium" class="company-details__CompanyContainer-sc-j5pyy8-0 VnOLK" style="margin: 0px; font-weight: 500; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px;"><span>LandscapAI</span></p>
                <p color="#000" font-size="medium" class="custom-field__CustomFieldContainer-sc-190n2f-0 dKSugh" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); margin: 0px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px;"><span>Automation + AI = Grow</span></p>
              </td>
              <td width="30">
                <div style="width: 30px;"></div>
              </td>
              <td color="#4358a7" direction="vertical" width="1" height="auto" class="color-divider__Divider-sc-1h38qjv-0 llIisW" style="width: 1px; border-bottom: none; border-left: 1px solid rgb(67, 88, 167);"></td>
              <td width="30">
                <div style="width: 30px;"></div>
              </td>
              <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr height="25" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                      <td width="30" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="vertical-align: bottom;"><span color="#4358a7" width="11" class="contact-info__IconWrapper-sc-mmkjr6-1 bglVXe" style="display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167);"><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/53/tools/email-signature-generator/icons/phone-icon-2x.png" color="#4358a7" alt="mobilePhone" width="13" class="contact-info__ContactLabelIcon-sc-mmkjr6-0 cnkwri" style="display: block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167);"></span></td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                      <td style="padding: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><a href="tel:855-242-4769" color="#000" class="contact-info__ExternalLink-sc-mmkjr6-2 ibLXSU" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 12px;"><span>855-242-4769</span></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr height="25" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                      <td width="30" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="vertical-align: bottom;"><span color="#4358a7" width="11" class="contact-info__IconWrapper-sc-mmkjr6-1 bglVXe" style="display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167);"><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/53/tools/email-signature-generator/icons/email-icon-2x.png" color="#4358a7" alt="emailAddress" width="13" class="contact-info__ContactLabelIcon-sc-mmkjr6-0 cnkwri" style="display: block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167);"></span></td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                      <td style="padding: 0px;"><a href="mailto:aaron@landscap.ai" color="#000" class="contact-info__ExternalLink-sc-mmkjr6-2 ibLXSU" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 12px;"><span>aaron@landscap.ai</span></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr height="25" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                      <td width="30" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="vertical-align: bottom;"><span color="#4358a7" width="11" class="contact-info__IconWrapper-sc-mmkjr6-1 bglVXe" style="display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167);"><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/53/tools/email-signature-generator/icons/link-icon-2x.png" color="#4358a7" alt="website" width="13" class="contact-info__ContactLabelIcon-sc-mmkjr6-0 cnkwri" style="display: block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167);"></span></td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                      <td style="padding: 0px;"><a href="//www.landscap.ai" color="#000" class="contact-info__ExternalLink-sc-mmkjr6-2 ibLXSU" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 12px;"><span>www.landscap.ai</span></a></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="width: 100%; vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td height="30"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td color="#4358a7" direction="horizontal" width="auto" height="1" class="color-divider__Divider-sc-1h38qjv-0 llIisW" style="width: 100%; border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(67, 88, 167); border-left: none; display: block;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="30"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="width: 100%; vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align: right; vertical-align: top;"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="width: 100%; vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td>
                <tr><div class="flex-container" style="display: flex;justify-content: space-evenly">
    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://updates.landscap.ai/widget/bookings/demolandscapai" color="#4358a7" class="cta__CtaButton-sc-sq0d6i-0 kGNEzu" style="border-width: 6px 12px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: 700; text-decoration: none; text-align: center; line-height: 40px; font-size: 12px; border-radius: 3px;">Customer Demo</a>
    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://updates.landscap.ai/widget/bookings/customersupportmeet" color="#4358a7" class="cta__CtaButton-sc-sq0d6i-0 kGNEzu" style="border-width: 6px 12px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: 700; text-decoration: none; text-align: center; line-height: 40px; font-size: 12px; border-radius: 3px;">Customer Support</a>
    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://updates.landscap.ai/widget/bookings/affiliatedemo" color="#4358a7" class="cta__CtaButton-sc-sq0d6i-0 kGNEzu" style="border-width: 6px 12px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: 700; text-decoration: none; text-align: center; line-height: 40px; font-size: 12px; border-radius: 3px;">Affiliate Demo</a>
</div></tr>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can see above that I added this style in the `span` tag surrounding your links:

```
<div style="display: flex;justify-content: space-evenly">
```

Also changed `span` to `div` and removed display block since div is basically a block version of span.
To make them the same width the easier way is with (not inline) css. You can use flex basis and target all elements inside the container (see above).

Comment: this specifically was labeled and mentioned as an HTML-Email question. Flexbox is only partially supported (~63%) by some providers.

Comment: I must say those labels were not there when I answered. YOU added them later on.

Comment: The [Timeline History](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77309514/timeline) says otherwise. Besides that the text already mentioned it to be an email signature before I edited the tags... Nice story - check your facts and provide proof if you want to call out "fake news"

Answer (score -2):

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="150" style="vertical-align: middle;"><span class="template3__ImageContainer-sc-vj949k-0 jeScQV" style="margin-right: 20px; display: block;"><img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/msgsndr/4v9YnFV91CVUbuwS6IF5/media/64f8b3af63e5711da26d77bf.png" role="presentation" width="130" class="image__StyledImage-sc-hupvqm-0 gYgOut" style="max-width: 130px;"></span></td>
              <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                <h2 color="#000" class="name__NameContainer-sc-1m457h3-0 jxbGUj" style="margin: 0px; font-size: 18px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-weight: 600;"><span>Aaron</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>Rajchel</span></h2>
                <p color="#000" font-size="medium" class="job-title__Container-sc-1hmtp73-0 ifJNJc" style="margin: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px;"><span>Owner</span></p>
                <p color="#000" font-size="medium" class="company-details__CompanyContainer-sc-j5pyy8-0 VnOLK" style="margin: 0px; font-weight: 500; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px;"><span>LandscapAI</span></p>
                <p color="#000" font-size="medium" class="custom-field__CustomFieldContainer-sc-190n2f-0 dKSugh" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); margin: 0px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px;"><span>Automation + AI = Grow</span></p>
              </td>
              <td width="30">
                <div style="width: 30px;"></div>
              </td>
              <td color="#4358a7" direction="vertical" width="1" height="auto" class="color-divider__Divider-sc-1h38qjv-0 llIisW" style="width: 1px; border-bottom: none; border-left: 1px solid rgb(67, 88, 167);"></td>
              <td width="30">
                <div style="width: 30px;"></div>
              </td>
              <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr height="25" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                      <td width="30" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="vertical-align: bottom;"><span color="#4358a7" width="11" class="contact-info__IconWrapper-sc-mmkjr6-1 bglVXe" style="display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167);"><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/53/tools/email-signature-generator/icons/phone-icon-2x.png" color="#4358a7" alt="mobilePhone" width="13" class="contact-info__ContactLabelIcon-sc-mmkjr6-0 cnkwri" style="display: block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167);"></span></td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                      <td style="padding: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><a href="tel:855-242-4769" color="#000" class="contact-info__ExternalLink-sc-mmkjr6-2 ibLXSU" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 12px;"><span>855-242-4769</span></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr height="25" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                      <td width="30" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="vertical-align: bottom;"><span color="#4358a7" width="11" class="contact-info__IconWrapper-sc-mmkjr6-1 bglVXe" style="display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167);"><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/53/tools/email-signature-generator/icons/email-icon-2x.png" color="#4358a7" alt="emailAddress" width="13" class="contact-info__ContactLabelIcon-sc-mmkjr6-0 cnkwri" style="display: block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167);"></span></td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                      <td style="padding: 0px;"><a href="mailto:aaron@landscap.ai" color="#000" class="contact-info__ExternalLink-sc-mmkjr6-2 ibLXSU" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 12px;"><span>aaron@landscap.ai</span></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr height="25" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                      <td width="30" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="vertical-align: bottom;"><span color="#4358a7" width="11" class="contact-info__IconWrapper-sc-mmkjr6-1 bglVXe" style="display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167);"><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/53/tools/email-signature-generator/icons/link-icon-2x.png" color="#4358a7" alt="website" width="13" class="contact-info__ContactLabelIcon-sc-mmkjr6-0 cnkwri" style="display: block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167);"></span></td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                      <td style="padding: 0px;"><a href="//www.landscap.ai" color="#000" class="contact-info__ExternalLink-sc-mmkjr6-2 ibLXSU" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 12px;"><span>www.landscap.ai</span></a></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="width: 100%; vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td height="30"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td color="#4358a7" direction="horizontal" width="auto" height="1" class="color-divider__Divider-sc-1h38qjv-0 llIisW" style="width: 100%; border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(67, 88, 167); border-left: none; display: block;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="30"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="width: 100%; vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align: right; vertical-align: top;"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table__StyledTable-sc-1avdl6r-0 kAbRZI" style="width: 100%; vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; font-family: Arial;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td>
                <tr><span style="display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;">
    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://updates.landscap.ai/widget/bookings/demolandscapai" color="#4358a7" class="cta__CtaButton-sc-sq0d6i-0 kGNEzu" style="border-width: 6px 12px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: 700; text-decoration: none; text-align: center; line-height: 40px; font-size: 12px; border-radius: 3px;">Customer Demo</a>
    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://updates.landscap.ai/widget/bookings/customersupportmeet" color="#4358a7" class="cta__CtaButton-sc-sq0d6i-0 kGNEzu" style="border-width: 6px 12px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: 700; text-decoration: none; text-align: center; line-height: 40px; font-size: 12px; border-radius: 3px;">Customer Support</a>
    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://updates.landscap.ai/widget/bookings/affiliatedemo" color="#4358a7" class="cta__CtaButton-sc-sq0d6i-0 kGNEzu" style="border-width: 6px 12px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(67, 88, 167); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: 700; text-decoration: none; text-align: center; line-height: 40px; font-size: 12px; border-radius: 3px;">Affiliate Demo</a>
</span></tr>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have made change in below line in which buttons are contains.

```
<span style="display: flex;justify-content: space-evenly;">
```

Comment: this specifically was labeled and mentioned as an HTML-Email question. Flexbox is only partially supported (~63%) by some providers.

Comment: @tacoshy Do you have any idea like how to fix in all supported browser? nowadays all latest browser support the flexbox.

Comment: as said, we do not talk about web browsers but emails that are opened in Email-clients. And email clients do not support flexbox. its not a website question, it is an email question

Comment: https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=flex

Comment: @tacoshy thank you for your kind information friend.